# Chrome extension using React.js causes "Manifest file is missing or unreadable" error

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-extension

I'm encountering the `Manifest file is missing or unreadable` error when trying to load my unpacked Chrome extension. I'm building the extension as a react app, so the file structure looks like this:

[image]

I understand that the `manifest.json` needs to be in the root folder, not in `public` the way react usually lays it out. When I move it to the root however, it breaks the connection to `app.js` and my popup only loads `index.html` with none of the javascript connected.

This is how my manifest is laid out:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Extension",
  "description": "This extension is a starting point to create a real Chrome extension",
  "version": "0.0.1",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html",
    "default_title": "Open the popup"
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "/public/images/get_started16.png",
    "48": "/public/images/get_started48.png",
    "128": "/public/images/get_started128.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
  ]
}
```

Comment: Since there can be only one root you need to move `src` inside `public` or make another common folder that will contain everything that's inside the extension package (and put manifest.json in that folder, of course).

Comment: Can you open popup, right click it and choose `inspect` > tab console and check error ?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you've figured this one out already since its been awhile since someone answered, but once you are done, do `npm run build`. This should create your "build" which will have your manifest file, after that, load unpackaged "build" folder.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Order to solve this issue :- Click on

1. Pack extension give a complete path Extension root directory click on Pack extension
2. Now click on Load extension.

you can see in your current folder two extra file generated on is `.pem` and `.ctx` file.

its working now